# Subspace of a Vector Space confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a confusion about Subspaces and i hope that can be cleared.. Say $E,F,G$ are subspaces of the same vector space. Say we want to show that $(E\cap F)+(E\cap G)$ is a subspace of  $E\cap(F+G)$.

My first question is, Does being a subspace necessarily mean being a subset? And if so, to show the mentioned above, do i have to, first, show that $(E\cap F)+(E\cap G) \subset E\cap(F+G)$ ?, i know three conditions have to be satisfied for a set to be a subspace of some vector space, and the first one among them is having the **zero vector** in it, How do i do that for the one above? I mean i don't know what is the **zero vector** for this vector space, Is it the same as the zero vector of the vector space of $E,F,G$ ? I was able to show that it is closed under addition and multiplication so that is not my question..

Thanks everyone!

Comment: First, how does your text/notes define the set $S + T$? And yes, we require $S \subset X$ to say $S$ is a subspace of $X$.

Comment: $S+T =\lbrace X=x+y \vert x\in S$ et $y\in T \rbrace$ @SeanRoberson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset, yes, it is necessary: For $x+y$, $x\in E\cap F$, $y\in E\cap G$, then as $E$ is a vector space and $x,y\in E$, then $x+y\in E$. Also, $x\in F$ and $y\in G$, so $x+y\in F+G$, so we conclude that $x+y\in E\cap(F+G)$.

Comment: So , if i'm asked to show whether B is a subspace of A, if $\exists a \in B$ but not in $A$, it's enough to conclude that $B$ isn't a subspace of $A$?.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: What about the zero vector?

Comment: There is only one zero vector, and that zero vector belongs to all $E,F,G$, and the ambient space, so it is apparently that the zero vector belongs to $(E\cap F)+(E\cap G)$.

Comment: So it's safe to assume that the zero vector is in there since every subspace has it.. Thanks for your time.